# Is "don't" considered informal In writing?

Tags: formal-language, informal-language, formality, contractions

Is "don't" considered informal In writing?
Originally, I thought that all contractions are informal, but I remember later I saw "don't"  also used in formal writings, or am I wrong?

Comment: I think really this is Off Topic subjective (formal according to whose preconceptions? *how* formal?). But in the end it's much the same as swearing - if it's not obvious to you you're writing in a context where other people write it, don't do it yourself. Basically - don't be the first to "lower the tone".

Comment: The "don't use contractions in formal contexts" guideline seems to be relaxing with time; the judicious use of them seems to be gaining acceptance. You can read various opinions on this at [this ELU question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20275). Be sure to read through the "possible duplicate" questions there as well!

Answer (score 4):

I would use "don't" in all but the most formal of writing. (Like, wedding invitations, an academic paper). Certainly for things like: a business letter, a note that you put on your door, an e-mail to someone you respect, etc., contractions are fine and failure to use them will make your writing sound overly formal.

Even in formal writing, which I occasionally have to do, I try to slip in "don't" and "can't" unless an editor catches me.

I don't like the comparison to swearing at all. As a foreign language learner you should basically never swear unless you are completely familiar with who you are talking to and you are using only words that they already used in similar contexts; otherwise you face a grave risk of offending them. But half of the native English speakers don't even know the "rule" that contractions are informal. You should definitely learn to use them all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it is a mistake to think that all speech is informal. Google some famous speeches - text that has been written, rehearsed and then spoken - and you'll find contractions. They are such a normal part of spoken English that language can even sound clumsy without them.

Over time, some contractions have even come to sound quite 'formal' themselves. For example, "*shan't*" (a contraction of 'shall not') sounds markedly more formal than "won't".

As 'formal' writing may well contain quotations of speech, it would also be wrong to say that such a text should never contain contractions.

The only kind of 'formal' writing that should perhaps not include contractions is perhaps that which is not meant to be spoken, such as orders or instuctions. For example, you would expect a notice to say "DO NOT ENTER". A sign saying "don't enter" just wouldn't convey the gravitas of an order.